# Adding Legend to PieChart

Tags: plotting, graphics, legending, charts

Say

```
counts = {0.18, 0.51, 0.31};

PieChart[counts, ChartLabels -> counts, PlotRange -> All,   Frame -> True, FrameTicks -> None]
```

I am completely puzzled how can I achieve a format like that of the following Figure.

[image]

Comment: Are you just interested in reproducing the figure, or do you need to do this programmatically for a number of data sets?

Comment: @MarcoB I want to do for other data sets as well. But instead of describing what I want, I thought it was a better idea to provide this figure as a guideline. (Thanks for your comment)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
counts = {0.18, 0.51, 0.31};
n = 600;
labels = Placed[Row /@ Thread[{Quantity[Round[100 counts], "Percent"], 
    " (" <> ToString@# <> "H)" & /@ Round[ n counts]}], "RadialOutside"];
legend = Placed[SwatchLegend[Automatic, Row /@ Thread[{{"CM ", "TD ", "TP "}, 
    Row[{"(", #, ")"}] & /@ Quantity[Round[100 counts], "Percent"]}]], 
   {After, Bottom}, Framed];

Framed[PieChart[counts, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, PlotRange -> All]]
```

[image]

Comment: Thank you for your answer! Exactly what I wanted. Just a question, How can I modify the associated text (in legend and in pie chart) show that it appears with the following option `Style["x", FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
 FontColor -> Black]` where "x", e.g. 18% (108H) or CM (18%) and so on.

Comment: @dimitris, you can add the option `LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 12, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", FontColor -> Black}` to `SwatchLegend`.

Comment: Thanks for your quick feedback. It works as desired but this affects only the associated `SwatchLegend`. I want also to affect accordingly the associated text that accompanies each pie.

Comment: @dimitris, add the same option to `PieChart`.

Comment: Perfect! Thanks a lot.