# Adjust graphics output for exporting

Tags: graphics, export, size

(Code based on the answer of @kgrl in the question titled [Adding Legend to PieChart](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/191203/adding-legend-to-piechart)).

I have two cases that apparently should result to same image size. The first:

```
TD = 8 + 12 + 12 + 12 + 33 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   15/2 + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2;
CM = 15/2 + (61 + 1/4) + (41 + 1/4)/2 + 
   24 + (3 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4) + (18 + 3/4)/2 + 14/2 + (24 + 3/4) + 
   9/2;
TP = 2*90;
countsDim = {CM, TD, TP}/(TD + TP + CM);

n = 384 + 179;
labels = Placed[
   Row /@ Thread[{Quantity[Round[100 countsDim], "Percent"], 
      " (" <> ToString@# <> " H)" & /@ {N[(n countsDim[[1]]), 5], 
        N[(n countsDim[[2]]), 5], Round@N[(n countsDim)[[3]]]}}], 
   "RadialOutside"];
legend = Placed[
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, 
    Row /@ Thread[{{"CM ", "TD ", "TP "}, 
       Row[{"(", #, ")"}] & /@ 
        Quantity[Round[100 countsDim], "Percent"]}], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
       FontColor -> Black}], {After, Bottom}, Framed];

type = Framed[
  PieChart[countsDim, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
     FontColor -> Black}, PlotTheme -> "NeonColor", 
   ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

and the second

```
L1 = 15 + 33 + 2*(61 + 1/4) + (24 + 3/4) + 2*90 + 12 + 12 + 
   12 + (4 + 1/2)/3;
L2 = (41 + 1/4) + (3 + 3/4) + (4 + 1/2)/3;
L3 = 8 + 24 + (4 + 1/2)/3 + 3*(18 + 3/4) + 14;
countsDim3 = {L1, L2, L3}/(L1 + L2 + L3);
 Nlist = {N[(n countsDim3)[[1]], 5], N[(n countsDim3)[[2]], 4], 
  N[(n countsDim3)[[3]], 5]}

n = 563;
labels = Placed[
   Row /@ Thread[{Quantity[Round[100 countsDim3], "Percent"], 
      " (" <> ToString@# <> " H)" & /@ Nlist}], "RadialOutside"];
legend = Placed[
   SwatchLegend[Automatic, 
    Row /@ Thread[{{"L1 ", "L2 ", "L3 "}, 
       Row[{"(", #, ")"}] & /@ 
        Quantity[Round[100 countsDim3], "Percent"]}], 
    LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman",
       FontColor -> Black}], {After, Bottom}, Framed];

niveau = Framed[
  PieChart[countsDim3, ChartLabels -> labels, ChartLegends -> legend, 
   PlotRange -> All, 
   LabelStyle -> {FontSize -> 14, FontFamily -> "Latin Modern Roman", 
     FontColor -> Black}, PlotTheme -> "NeonColor", 
   ImageSize -> Medium]]
```

However, the two figures do not have the same dimensions

[image]

I have a series of similar figures that I want to export to Latex. I have been searching here and elsewhere but I could not find a solution to my question.
What should I do in order to get Figures of the same dimensions (this apply to everything-circle, legend, text, etc.)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Please try replacing, in each of **type** and **niveau**

```
ImageSize -> Medium
```

with fixed width and height values, for example

```
ImageSize -> {300, 240}
```

[image: Equally sized pie charts]